Face intersect while keeping objects separate
I want to do a "Face" -> "Intersect (knife)" between two objects, but keep the objects separate. This intersect seems to only work if the objects are joined? As far as I know separating joined objects after a face intersect can be arbitrarily difficult for complex meshes.
If joining the meshes is unavoidable... is there some trick for selecting only one of the objects? "Select linked" can be arbitrarily difficult for meshes with many separate parts and internal pockets. Using a Boolean modifier is out since on the current version of Blender (4.2), the Boolean modifier officially does not support non-manifold objects (it will produce a sometimes right, sometimes bugged, output).



Enter edit mode on the first object
Select all its vertices and add them to a vertex group
Join the two objects and enter edit mode
Use the vertex group to select the first object
Perform the "Face" -> "Intersect (knife)"
Use the vertex group to select the first object
"Select" -> "Select linked" -> "Linked"
"Mesh" -> "Separate" -> "Selection"

This does not work when using "Intersect (knife)"'s "Separate mode" "All".


Why don't you use the knife tool instead ? I suppose it can do what you are trying to do just fine while keeping the object separated.

Here, the two cubes are two different objects and knifing them don't join them in the hierarchy.
For the selection part, using the L keyboard selects objects over your mouse cursor, might try that aswell ?
Not sure it will help you but can't tell without more context.

In edit mode, "Face" -> "Intersect (knife)" is a different feature than the "knife" tool. I need the precision/complexity/automation of not doing the operation by hand. I updated the question to be more clear.
